# Get the password from the webservices URL and access through that password

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have a Webservices URL which appends with accesscode. I need to post accesscode to a webservices URL and get json response. I am getting json response with correct accesscode and with incorrect accesscode too. I am not getting where the issue arising. I need to display alert when wrong password enters.

Here is my code:

```
  NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"txtsecurecode=%@",[txtsecurecode text]];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

      [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://my example.com/Accountservice/Security/ValidateAccess?accesscode=abcdtype=1"]]];

        NSURL *url;

  // I need to parse it into url here .  

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSURLConnection *conn= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        if(conn)
        {
            NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
        }

    NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If I give wrong password, I am getting login failed, that's fine. when I correct password, it doesn't showing the content of that URL. We need to parse the request into URL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**In Your case**

```
 NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://my example.com/Accountservice/Security/ValidateAccess?accesscode=abcd&type=1"]];
```

You can not pass **parameter** with `URL in POST` method such like ,
 `....?accesscode=abcd&type=1"`

You can use the following code snippet, as described [in this article](http://panditpakhurde.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/posting-data-to-url-in-objective-c/):

Here, I simple describe how can use of POST method.

> **1.** Set post string with actual username and password.
>
> ```
> NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&Username=%@&Password=%@",@"username",@"password"];
> ```
>
> **2.** Encode the post string using `NSASCIIStringEncoding` and also the post string you need to send in NSData format.
>
> ```
> NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
> ```
>
> You need to send the actual length of your data. Calculate the length
>   of the post string.
>
> ```
> NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
> ```
>
> **3.** Create a Urlrequest with all the properties like `HTTP` method, http header field with length of the post string. Create `URLRequest`
>   object and initialize it.
>
> ```
> NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
> ```
>
> Set the Url for which your going to send the data to that request.
>
> ```
> [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abcde.com/xyz/login.aspx"]]];
> ```
>
> Now, set **HTTP** method (*POST or GET*). Write this lines as it is in
>   your code.
>
> ```
> [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
> ```
>
> Set `HTTP` header field with length of the post data.
>
> ```
> [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
> ```
>
> Also set the Encoded value for HTTP header Field.
>
> ```
> [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
> ```
>
> Set the `HTTPBody` of the urlrequest with postData.
>
> ```
> [request setHTTPBody:postData];
> ```
>
> **4.** Now, create URLConnection object. Initialize it with the URLRequest.
>
> ```
> NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
> ```
>
> It returns the initialized url connection and begins to load the data
>   for the url request. You can check that whether you `URL` connection
>   is done properly or not using just **if/else** statement as below.
>
> ```
> if(conn)
> {
> NSLog(@”Connection Successful”)
> }
> else
> {
> NSLog(@”Connection could not be made”);
> }
> ```
>
> **5.** To receive the data from the HTTP request , you can use the delegate methods provided by the URLConnection Class Reference.
>   Delegate methods are as below.
>
> ```
> - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
> ```
>
> Above method is used to receive the data which we get using post
>   method.
>
> ```
> - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
> ```
>
> This method , you can use to receive the error report in case of
>   connection is not made to server.
>
> ```
> - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
> ```
>
> The above method is used to process the data after connection has made
>   successfully.

**Also Refer** [This](http://deusty.blogspot.in/2006/11/sending-http-get-and-post-from-cocoa.html) **and** [This](http://yuvarajmanickam.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/nsurlconnection-basics-for-ios-beginners/) **documentation** for `POST` method.

And here is best example with source code of [HTTPPost Method.](http://kemal.co/index.php/2012/02/fetching-data-with-getpost-methods-by-using-nsurlconnection/)

Comment: @patel, I updated my code as you suggested, still I my app logging for wrng password. To set up the url, I didnt used like you said, because I am getting a new url as a json response. I updated my question with your code. you can see the last statement in my code, how I used the url. Awaiting for reply.

Comment: ...?accesscode=abcdtype=1 you can not pass it in Post method check in line that i put in my answer.