# how to pass Array as parameter in http body in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, web-services, restkit

I have below code(httpbody for service) in php:-

```
<$xmlJobList = "<?xml version='1.0'?><Search><CompanyId><![CDATA[ $companyId ]]></CompanyId>"; $xmlJobList .= "<Offset><![CDATA[ $offset ]]></Offset><Limit><![CDATA[ $limit ]]></Limit>";$xmlJobList .= "<Keywords><![CDATA[ $keywords ]]></Keywords>";$xmlJobList .= "<FunctionalAreaId><![CDATA[ $farea ]]></FunctionalAreaId>**<IndustryTypeIds>"; foreach ($industry as $value){$xmlJobList .= "<IndustryTypeId><![CDATA[ $value ]]></IndustryTypeId>";}$xmlJobList .= "<Format><![CDATA[ $format ]]></Format></Search>";
```

and i want to write the HTTP body for iPhone/objective-c

PLease help me for this, i am working very 1st time for php.

Comment: for Post Method Read this mine answer .....- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377212/get-the-password-from-the-webservices-url-and-access-through-that-password/15377242#15377242