# How to sign HTTP requests with user credentials for mobile app and backend server communication?

Tags: php, android, ios, http, oauth-2.0

We have a pretty standard scenario - a mobile app communication with a backend PHP server API via HTTP POST and GET. A user must login in mobile app in order to do anything, so every  request from mobile app to our server needs to be signed with user credentials. Userid and password are saved in mobile app internal settings after successful login, so a user does not need to reenter it again.

Previously, backend PHP webservices were developed by other guys, but now we need to implement it ourselves. When looking at previous projects, they required to pass user credentials for every request. I'm posting several request examples below. All data insert/update web services use POST, but userid and pwd are passed inside body with other data (Save Car). All data select services pass userid and its password via GET params.

Is it the best and secure way? Maybe we should put sha1(userid+password=salt) into HTTP authorization header and leave userid in body (because we need to select user pass from database in server)? Or maybe we could use OAuth 2 in mobile app for signing HTTP request (generating userid+pass+... to authorization  header) and use OAuth 2 in backend to generate the same hash and check if it's the same? I could'n find any straightforward way how to use OAuth 2 for PHP just for signing request, so any help would be appreciated :) Also, related info about what libraries to use for iOS/Android development would be also appreciated.

**LOGIN**

```
HTTP method: POST
URL: http://mybackend.com/login
BODY:

 { "uid" : 123,
   "pwd" : "3CB3E2E6AECA48C41000119767B561F5E9E66229" // contains sha1(pass+salt)
 }
```

**GET CAR LIST**

```
HTTP method: GET
URL: http://mybackend.com/getCars?uid=123&pwd=3CB3E2E6AECA48C41000119767B561F5E9E66229
```

**SAVE CAR**

```
HTTP method: POST
URL: http://mybackend.com/saveCar
BODY:

  { "uid" : 123,
    "pwd" : "3CB3E2E6AECA48C41000119767B561F5E9E66229",
    "car" : 
    { "id" : 111,
      "name": "My car"
    }
 }
```

Comment: for POST method ...look at my ans...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377212/get-the-password-from-the-webservices-url-and-access-through-that-password/15377242#15377242

Comment: I suggest using an Authorization Key in the Authorization header. You would generate this when the user signs in and then use it for any further requests. If you use this, you don't have to put the user id in the body anymore, because you would have a one-to-one relationship between the Authorization Key and the User Id, so you can easily check server-side if the Authorization Key is valid.

Comment: @Cosmin I assume this Authorization Key is a similar concept to access token? In such case the token would also need to have some expiration date.

Comment: Yes, it would work like an access token. And you can give it an expiration date if the context of your app requires it, but not completely needed, I guess it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I may ask if user can change password in app then is it updating that password with the saved one in app code?

better way to post data as make a directory of access_token and use userid and password in it.
 as for Example :
{
 **"access_token":{
                  "uid" : 123,
                  "pwd" : "3CB3E2E6AECA48C41000119767B561F5E9E66229"
                }**,
 "saveCar" : {
                 "id" : 111,
                 "name": "My car"
             }
}

and at the sever side php code be easy to access your all url with this accesstoken by checking with database and allowing you access to do the saveCar in database.
else from sever side you will have error message as access failed to login try again with login.
and use it in post method with all requests.
will be good for security type.
POST method is one for PHP data security.
no other thing you need for this.

Instead of using GET HTTP request for car list, you can POST the access token to your url as

{
 **"access_token":{
                  "uid" : 123,
                  "pwd" : "3CB3E2E6AECA48C41000119767B561F5E9E66229",
                }**
}
to your URL for Carlist.
*http://mybackend.com/getCars?*  from that post method, do the code for as in result of this post method returns the list of cars.

Thanks, Hope  this description can help you.