# iOS - Potential leak of an object allocated

Tags: ios, nsdata, nsmutableurlrequest

I am getting Potential leak in postdata(NSData- below code ) error.

Can anyone please tell me how to solve these issues? also  I saw   memory leak in my code [Using the build and analyze of XCode]:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults   = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *SessionId        = [defaults objectForKey:@"SessionId"];
NSString *versionid       = [appdetails objectForKey:@"versionId"] ;


NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Comment: 1. Are you using ARC? 2. Where is the static analyzer suggesting that there is A memory leak?

Comment: for use POST method best Example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377212/get-the-password-from-the-webservices-url-and-access-through-that-password/15377242#15377242

Answer (score 0):

Anything that you alloc (allocate) memory for needs to be released, unless you are using ARC. Try this:

Replace

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
```

With

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

The second piece of code creates an autoreleased object so you dont need to release it manually.