# Request failed 'JSON'

Tags: iphone, ios, json, ios5

I have JSON format like below i need to post request to sever but the response from the server is error 500.

> {"firstName":"Sharath K", "lastName":"babu",
>   "moMerchantAddresses":[{"email":"abc@abc.co.in"}]} >

```
 NSMutableArray *objects =  [NSMutableArray  arrayWithObjects:@"Sharath",@"babu",@"[{\"email\":\"abc@abc.co.in\"}]", nil];
        NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"firstName",@"lastName",@"moMerchantAddresses", nil];
NSMutableDictionary  *jsonDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:nil];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[jsonData length]];

ServiceInterface *service = [[ServiceInterface alloc] init];
service.theDelegate = self;
service.theSuccessMethod = @selector(responseMerchantCreationService:);
service.theFailureMethod = @selector(requestFailedWithError:);
[self addServiceInterfaceToServiceStack:service];
NSString* stringURL  =  [kBase_URL stringByAppendingString:@"/merchant/create"];

NSString* webStringURL  =  [stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL* url  =  [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];


NSLog(@"request file :: %@",request);
[service startWithRequest:request];
service = nil;
```

Please Help me in this

Comment: for basic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377212/get-the-password-from-the-webservices-url-and-access-through-that-password/15377242#15377242

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may helps you .

```
NSMutableDictionary *emailDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
[emailDict setObject:@"abc@abc.co.in" forKey:@"email"];

NSMutableArray *emailArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[emailArr addObject:emailDict];

NSMutableDictionary *mainDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
[mainDict setObject:@"Sharath" forKey:@"firstName"];
[mainDict setObject:@"babu" forKey:@"lastName"];
[mainDict setObject:emailDict forKey:@"moMerchantAddresses"];

Now change this mainDict to NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mainDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:nil];
```